# Can MSstatsTMT be used for both MS2 and MS3 runs?

Tags: proteomics

MSstatsTMT is an R library for statistical analysis of TMT labeled mass-spectrometry (MS) proteomics data. The [documentation](http://msstats.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/MSstatsTMT.html) does not explicitly mention the kind of MS that can be processed. The examples contain comments that contain both MS2 and MS3, but I would like to make sure that is indeed the case. Can anyone confirm that and maybe provide an example script?